# Inject session scoped bean in every request scoped bean

Tags: session, jsf-2, managed-bean

In order to keep basic information about the user (security roles, personal datas, etc...) in the session, I've created an AppSession bean, and I was wondering if it was a bad practice to inject in every backing bean a reference of that session bean.

For example, instead of this in a request scoped bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyRequestBean {
     @ManagedProperty("#{appSession.user}")
     private User user;

     @ManagedProperty("#{appSession.roles}")
     private Roles[] roles;    
}
```

I'd like to have something like this...

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyRequestBean {
     @ManagedProperty("#{appSession}")
     private AppSession appSession;
}
```

...and use *appSession* to retrieves user and roles datas.

What do you think of this, is there some bad practises uses here?

PS: sorry, I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: It's back to front. You should be injecting the beans into the session, and into each other, not the other way round. You don't actually need the session itself at all directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I was wondering if it was a bad practice to inject in every backing bean a reference of that session bean.*

It's not. It does the job you want. Only other way would be manually grabbing it via `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()` or `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`. But those ways are not declarative and therefore a "less good" practice.